# Grunt server not working in nitrous.io

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, nitrousio

I created a node env using [nitrous.io](http://www.nitrous.io).  Inside of their terminal I installed [yeoman](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUQ1fvdO9GY&list=PLzofFjB0bZ7V6OnWDiZnb-JGqivTrc0Uc).
If I try to run `grunt server` I get an error stating:

```
Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt                                                                                                                                                                                                           
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about                                                                                                                                                                                                         
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:                                                                                                                                                                                                           

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

If i go to preview than connect to port 3000 i get this

[image: error message]

The Reference states for node to change 127.0.0.1 or "localhost" to 0.0.0.0

```
  var http = require('http');
  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
  }).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
  console.log('Server running at http://0.0.0.0:3000/');
```

Grunt syntaxes are a bit different for a server

```
connect: {
      options: {
        port: 3000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: '0.0.0.0' // 
      },
```

Even after this change the errors persist. Failing when I run `grunt server` or go to preview port 3000

Any ideas on what I'm doing incorrect?  How do I run my grunt server so I may see my site in the broswer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the comments this worked for me:

```
gem install sass; gem install compass
yo webapp
```

Edit `Gruntfile.js` around line 43:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 3000, // <- changed this line
    livereload: 35729,
    hostname: '0.0.0.0' // <- changed this line
```

Run `grunt server` and click on the *Preview*-Button / *Port 3000*.

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through the advice on the first error message you got? You need both `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json` (with Grunt listed as a dependency); [this is covered in the official documentation](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started). Then, by running `npm install` you will be able to pull down a local Grunt to your project.

Comment: This is my absolute first time using any of this technology.  Coming from a brief background in rails. I just forgot to do the npm install or bundle install.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm marking it correct but do you know why I had to grunt server --force for the server to work?  It was throwing an error about compass and now  The bootstrap default styles do not work and I fear it's because of the force

Comment: If you're using sass or compass through Grunt you must make sure that the gems are installed on your system. Was this the error thrown? npm doesn't handle those packages, only the Grunt compatible wrappers, so if you don't have those installed do that first. :)

Comment: is package.json = gemfile?  also shouldnt the gemfile have it seeing that i'm using yeoman?  Thanks so much for your help

Comment: No, those two tasks just require that you have the gems installed globally; i.e. `gem update --system; gem install sass; gem install compass`